# Windows 8.1 Mouse pointer will not switch from Default

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse

I have a high DPI monitor, so I tend to use the large Mouse cursors.  Recently, regardless of what cursor theme I select, it uses the default theme.

It doesn't even work if I specifically change a single cursor.

I have created a new user and the different mouse themes will load for a while, but some setting or something makes it stop working again.

Has anyone else seen this issue, and is there a way to diagnose and fix it?

Comment: Oddly, today, the mouse pointer popped to the correct setting, in the middle of a session.  I hope it sticks.. This is puzzling.